# Sufficient bound to conclude limit has certain value. $\lim {\left( {\int_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}} } \right)^n}=\frac 1 2 $

Tags: integration, limits, asymptotics, definite-integrals

I am trying to show that

$$\lim {\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}} } \right)^n}=\frac 1 2 $$

Now, this can be done as follows. Using $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ we get that

$$\int\limits_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}}  =\int\limits_1^\infty {{{nx^{n-1}} \over {1 + {x^n}}}} \frac{dx}{nx}$$

Upon integrating by parts we get

$$\int\limits_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}}  =  - {{\log 2} \over n} + \int\limits_1^\infty  {{{\log \left( {1 + {x^n}} \right)} \over {n{x^2}}}dx} $$

or 
$$\int\limits_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}}  = 1 - {{\log 2} \over n} + \int\limits_1^\infty  {{{\log \left( {1 + {x^n}} \right) - n} \over {n{x^2}}}dx} $$ since $\int_1^\infty x^{-2}dx=1$.

Using $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ once again on the RHS, we get

$$\int\limits_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}}  = 1 - {{\log 2} \over n} + \int\limits_0^1 {{{\log \left( {1 + {x^n}} \right) - n\log x - n} \over n}dx} $$

But since $\int_0^1 \log x=-1=\int_0^1 dx$

$$\int\limits_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}}  = 1 - {{\log 2} \over n} + {1 \over n}\int\limits_0^1 {\log \left( {1 + {x^n}} \right)dx} $$

Now, since for $x\geq 0$, $\log(1+x)\leq x$, we get $$\int\limits_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}}  \le 1 - {{\log 2} \over n} + {1 \over n}\int\limits_0^1 {{x^n}dx}  = 1 - {{\log 2} \over n} + {1 \over {n\left( {n + 1} \right)}}$$ which means

$$\int\limits_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}}  = 1 - {{\log 2} \over n} + O\left( {{1 \over {{n^2}}}} \right)$$

Is this enough to conclude that

$${\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {{{dx} \over {1 + {x^n}}}} } \right)^n} = {e^{ - \log 2}} = {1 \over 2}\text{ ? }$$

If so, how?

Comment: I am all in favor of using `\limits` in titles, but this one was too large! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hehe, no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question can be recast as: if
$$
a_n=1+\frac{a}{n}+O\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr),
$$
is it true that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^n=e^a?
$$
The answer is yes. Since $\log(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$ as $x\to0$, we have
$$
\log a_n=\frac{a}{n}+O\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr).
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n\log a_n}=e^a.
$$

Comment: No, it will not work with $O(1/n)$, since you need the limit of $n\log a_n$. It will work however with $o(1/n)$.

Comment: To restate Julián's result: if $c_n\to c$, then $\left(1+{c_n\over n}\right)^n\to e^c$. This even works for complex numbers $c_n$.

Comment: Oh, right, the $n$ would make things go awry. Maybe I failed to understand how you work when getting $O$ inside $O$s?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I don't think that is what Julián states. (?)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff What I write is slightly more general. I don't care about the rate of convergence of $c_n$ to $c$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Oh, well. I see now that what you write implies what I ask, by using $\frac 1 n O(\frac 1 n)$ instead of $O(n^{-2})$, right?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Right. All you need is $\int\limits_0^1 {\log \left( {1 + {x^n}} \right)dx}\to0$ and you're done.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: your restatement is essentially my comment about equicontinuous functions in my answer since $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ is an equicontinuous sequence on compact sets.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-2cm}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^n}\right)^n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\int_0^1\frac{x^n\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^n}\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\int_0^1\frac{x\mathrm{d}x^n}{1+x^n}\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\left[\frac1nx\log(1+x^n)\right]_0^1+\frac1n\int_0^1\log(1+x^n)\mathrm{d}x\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\log(2)+\frac1n\int_0^1\log(1+x^n)\mathrm{d}x\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\log(2)+\frac1n\int_0^1O(x^n)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^n\tag{$\log(1+x^n)\le x^n$}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\log(2)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\left(\log(2)+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\right)^n\\
&=e^{-\log(2)}\\
\end{align}
$$
Note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n\right)$ when $\{f_n\}$ are [equicontinuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity) at $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$.

In this case
$$
f_n(x)=\left(1-\frac xn\right)^n
$$
and
$$
x_n=\log(2)+O\left(\frac1n\right)
$$

Comment: The statement on equicontinuity is worth reading about.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int^{1}_{0} \frac{dx}{1+x^{n}}\right)^{n} = e^{\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int^{1}_{0} \frac{dx}{1+x^{n}}-1\right)n}$$

But $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int^{1}_{0} \frac{dx}{1+x^{n}}-1\right)n = -\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int^{1}_{0}x[\ln(1+x^{n})]'dx\right)=$$

$$ -\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x\ln(1+x^{n})|^{1}_{0} + \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^{1}_{0}\ln(1+x^{n})dx=-\ln 2$$

because $\ln(1+x^{n}) \leq x^{n}$ it involves $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^{1}_{0}\ln(1+x^{n})dx = 0$$

The conclusion is immediate.

Comment: Did you read the other work, both by myself and the answerers? I'm not saying your answer is not helpful, but it really doesn't add anything new of what has already been said.

Comment: Also, how do you justify the first step equation?