# $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx)^n$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx\right)^n$$

I solved this problem as in the link:
[Click here](https://brilliant.org/problems/what-is-the-limit/)
I got the answer as $0$ but it says incorrect. I think the answer is wrong or there is some error with the question.

**My try:**
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_0^1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^mx^{mn}dx\right)^n$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{1+mn}\right)^n$$
$$=\color{blue}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac{\Phi(-1,1,\frac1n)}{n}\right)^n=0 ????}$$

**Do you think the problem is incorrect or answer is incorrectly provided by the author ?**

Comment: Just using mathematica I found the answer was $\frac{1}{2}$. Going to see if I can write the process up as an answer rather than an inscrutable black box

Comment: Enter screenshot of mathematica input only. I wanna see

Comment: You can rewrite this as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]^n}\frac{d^nx}{\prod_{i=1}^n1+x_i^n}$$ Which suggests this should be solvable with the law of large numbers, but I don't have enough experience in probability to know how to connect the dots.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309500/42969

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may just use

- $\lim_{t\to 0}(1-t)^{\frac 1t} = e^{-1}$

Now, write

\begin{eqnarray*}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx\right)^n
& = & \left(1- \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} dx}_{=:J_n}\right)^n
\end{eqnarray*}

Using integration by parts you get
$$J_n = \frac 1n\int_0^1 x\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^n} dx = \frac 1n\left(\ln 2 - \underbrace{\int_0^1 \ln (1+x^n) dx}_{=:I_n}\right)$$

Now, DCT (or just squeezing) gives immediately
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }I_n = 0$$

All together

\begin{eqnarray*}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx\right)^n
& = & \left(\left(1-\frac{\ln 2 - I_n}n\right)^{\frac{n}{\ln 2 - I_n}}\right)^{\ln 2 - I_n} \\
& \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} & \left(e^{-1}\right)^{\ln2} = \frac 12
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Beautiful simply

Comment: @AmanRajput Thank you very much for your appreciation. :-)

Comment: You can say that $$
0 < \int_0^1 {\log (1 + x^n )dx}  \le \int_0^1 {x^n dx}  = \frac{1}{{n + 1}}.
$$ So no need to refer to DCT.

Comment: @Gary Yes. That's another nice way to see that the integrals $I_n$ converge to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $I_n$ be given by the integral $I_n=\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx$.  Enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ and reveals

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\frac1n \int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/n}}{x(1+x)}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

Using partial fraction expansion on the integrand in $(1)$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\frac1n \int_0^1 x^{1/n-1}\,dx-\frac1n \int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/n}}{1+x}\,dx\\\\
&=1-\frac1n \int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/n}}{1+x}\,dx\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

Next, using $1+x\le e^x\le \frac1{1-x}$ for $x<1$ provides the estimates

$$e^{\frac1n\log(x)}-1\ge \frac{\log(x)}{n}$$

and for $x\in (0,1)$

$$\begin{align}
e^{\frac1n\log(x)}-1\le \frac{\frac{\log(x)}{n} }{1-\frac{\log(x)}{n}}\le \frac{\log(x)}{n}+\left(\frac{\log(x)}{n} \right)^2
\end{align}$$

Using these estimates in $(2)$, we can assert that

$$I_n=1-\frac{\log(2)}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\tag3$$

---

Finally, raising both sides of $(3)$ to the $n$'th power and letting $n\to \infty$ yields the coveted limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}I_n^n&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{\log(2)}n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)^n\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

Comment: Perhaps the term $O(1/n)$ needs some explanation. Why the dependence on the $\log x$ (which blows up at $x=0$) can be ignored? The $e^w =1+O(w)$ works for $w$ near $0$.

Comment: @Gary The logarithm function is $L^1$.  There is absolutely no issue.

Comment: I know and see why this should work but again $\log x /n$ is large near $x=0$, so the approximation $e^w =1+O(w)$ is not valid.

Comment: @gary If you like, then write the integral as $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_\varepsilon^1 $.  Then, for each $\varepsilon>0$ the expansion is valid and we can proceed accordingly.

Comment: @Gary Alternatively, we assert that $\frac{\log(x)}{n}\le e^{\frac1n \log(x)}-1\le \frac{\frac{\log(x)}{n}}{1-\frac{\log(x)}{n}}\le \frac{\log(x)}{n}+\left(\frac{\log(x)}{n}\right)^2$

Comment: @Gary I've edited to ensure that the development is rigorous now.  Thank you for alerting me to the issue you raised.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @amanrajput Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I  really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

Picture of MMA input as requested:
[image: MMA input]

Comment: Thank you please tell your mathematica version. I will download too ! Looks more fascinating than Wolfram Alpha

Comment: Its version 12.2 I believe

Comment: Thank you I just installed it.. faced too much difficulty haha don't know how to input infinity with shortcut at the moment. But I managed to do it. It seems different than Wolfram Alpha, but it is more powerful I guess

Answer (score 0):

Your answer cannot be correct.

Since, by your argument,  $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x^n}>1-\frac{1}{1+n}$$

A lower bound for your limit is:

$$\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^n\to \frac1e$$